# API Deployment on Kubernetes, pods are not creating

Tags: kubernetes

I'm deploying APi on kubernetes but POD'S are not creating getting error:

```
unable to ensure pod container exists: failed to create container for [kubepods burstable pod63951ed1-a42f-44c9-9f85-fbb4c06a3e83] : mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/kubepods/burstable/pod63951ed1-a42f-44c9-9f85-fbb4c06a3e83: cannot allocate memory
```

YAML file:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: abc
  labels:
    app: abc
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vaccndev
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: abc
        app: abc
    spec:
      hostname: abc
      containers:
      - name: abc
        image: docker.repo1.xyz.com/va_nonuser/server:Dev
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 2Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 1Gi
```

Comment: `docker.repo1.xyz.com` seems not like a valid container registry. What application do you want to run?

Comment: what platform are you using for Kubernetes? is it a custom cluster looks are node have insufficient memory maybe.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/841

Comment: Besides labels/selectors issues between `app: abc` and `app: vaccndev`, please provide more details about your environment. could you try with another image?  What are you getting with `free -m` command? Please provide your nodes resources. Its on local env or cloud env?